# Place images in elliptic shape

Tags: css, position

Hei, I would like to know if there is an easier way to arrange some images in elliptical shape in CSS as you can see in the image below (slightly turned to the right).

I have tried using position absolute on each image but that would not be a fluid architecture on resize and zoom. Tried to go on Adobe Illustrator, create everything, export it as SVG but it turns out I get a transparent box around it that doesn't let me scale the circles properly.

If you have any suggestions at all, please let me know. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You can use `border-radius: 100%` in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Elliptical Images - Option 1: Border radius**

You can set a border-radius of 50% on the images to make them elliptical, but make sure their ratio is squared. Non-square image will not form a perfect circle. 
For example:

```
.image {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50% 50%;
}
```

[Browser support (most browsers)](https://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius)

**Elliptical Images - Option 2: Clip-path**

Another option you could use, but has a less deeper browser support is clip-path. You can achieve the same, but also add transitions/ animations to it if you want.

Example:
Set a background image on a div and add the clip-path property:

```
.divclassname{
    clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
}
```

Source:
[Clip path MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)
[Browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility)

**Responsive behaviour**

To get a good responsive behaviour you can set the unit in percentage '%' for the top and left position. Of course this depends on what you are using in your code. This allows the images respond to their parent when scaling/resizing. It is possible you would need 1 or 2 media queries to adjust or tweak it a little on some screen sizes (mostly mobile/tablet).

In case you want to style each image on a different position you can use different classes on each image or the nth-child selector:

```
.image:nth-child(1) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
}
.image:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 40%;
}
Etc.
```

[Source: nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)